# Getting "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" while using panGestureRecognizer for slide out view

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I've Slide out view controller and it works perfectly until the view controller calls out performSegue to another view controller. I'm getting below error with reference to `panGestureRecognizer`, which is used in parent view controller to slide out.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is the code possible causing issue, this code is in the destination view controller:

```
sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController()
sidebarButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```

When I comment 3rd line above, segue to destination view controller works but side out function from destination view controller doesn't work. Hope this additional details helps.

Comment: show your gesture recogniser function

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan I've added some context here now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that string is a valid key.

You are dealing with optionals, so conditionally unwrap each return object before using it.

Forced unwrapping is dangerous and should only be used when you are absolutely sure that an optional contains a value.

Comment: We live in a great age where compilers and runtimes tell you exactly what is wrong, in plain english (most of the time). We should be grateful and listen more!

Comment: @a4arpan I've added additional context here now